# conditional nsarray count

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I want a count on an array where a sub array meets a condition.
I thought I could do this, but I can't.

```
NSLog(@"%d",[[_sections enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            [[obj objectAtIndex:4] isEqualToString:@"1"];
        }] count]);
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What outcome do you expect, and what's your input data?

Comment: count doesn't come up in the code autocomplete, and it shows the error "Bad receiver type 'void'"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` doesn't return anything.   I'd bet that code won't even compile (and, as your comment states, auto-completion doesn't work -- and it shouldn't).

Use NSArray's `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:`
 and take the `count` of the resulting `NSIndexSet`.

[Documented here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)

Comment: indexOfObjectPassingTest says it returns the first occurrence.

Comment: @Darren - typo in the answer, indexES... instead.

Comment: Right. There's a plural method: index**es**OfObject**s**PassingTest. It returns an NSIndex**Set**.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the typos.  SO prior to first coffee is rife with stupid.

Comment: Thanks, I did eventually spot the 2 different indexOfObject/indexesOfObjects. I now have this, but it returns -1 of what the actual result should be!
        NSLog(@"HERE: %d",[[_sections indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            if ([[obj objectAtIndex:4] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
                return TRUE;
            } else {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }] count]);

Comment: TRUE and FALSE should be YES and NO, but that shouldn't impact the result.   The %d should likely be %u or %lu and that might impact it. Try printing the resulting NSIndexSet itself (and not just the count).

Answer (score 2):

bbum is right; you should use indexesOfObjectsPassingTest. It's more straightforward.

But you *could* use `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` to count test-passers, like this:

```
NSArray *sections = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"arb", @"1", @"misc", @"1", @"extra", nil];
NSMutableArray *occurrencesOf1 = [NSMutableArray array];
[sections enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([(NSString*)obj isEqualToString:@"1"])
        [occurrencesOf1 addObject:obj];
}];
NSLog(@"%d", [occurrencesOf1 count]); // prints 2
```

It's inefficient because it requires that extra mutable array.

(So you should check bbum's answer as the accepted one -- but I'm new at block functions too, and appreciated the puzzle.)

Comment: Refinement;  use a `__block NSUInteger count = 0;` outside the block and increment inside on passing test.  More efficient than creating an array.  Whether or not it is more efficient than creating an NSIndexSet could only be resolved through testing (__block has overhead and NSIndexSet is very cheap).

Comment: +1 this is exactly why Stack Overflow allows for multiple answers besides the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

[It's faster to use a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21157109/which-has-faster-performance-indexesofobjectspassingtest-or-filteredarrayusingpr) (and, IMO, more readable):

```objective-c
    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[self countSectionsWithValue:@"1" atIndex:4]);
    // ...
}

// ...

- (NSUInteger) countSectionsWithValue:(NSString *)value atIndex:(NSInteger)idx
{
    NSUInteger count = 0
    for (id section in _sections)
    {
        if ([[section objectAtIndex:idx] isEqualToString:value])
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Also note that I used the proper `%lu` format and `(unsigned long)` type in the `NSLog`. `%d` isn't descriptive and [doesn't act the same in all scenarios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Type_field).